# Interpret Windows Error Report

Tags: c#, exception, crash-reports, windows-error-reporting

My program randomly crashes with the error log shown below. The problem is related to sockets or thread-safety.

My question is, what kind of exceptions is this?

```
"Problem Signature 09: A4DH5WWIWWW1YJTMP0C0KV4ZWCALU4IN"
```

Usually is something interpretable. I googled it and it looks like others had it too, so it's not an particular error.

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: nmlb.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 532af97c
  Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.30319.17929
  Problem Signature 06: 4ffa561c
  Problem Signature 07: 210e
  Problem Signature 08: 1e
  Problem Signature 09: A4DH5WWIWWW1YJTMP0C0KV4ZWCALU4IN
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: In my case A4DH5WWIWWW1YJTMP0C0KV4ZWCALU4IN was a System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException. Also Event Viewer provides additional info grabbed by the .NET Runtime (I think in debug mode only).